# If a live ac wire of 220 V, 50 Hz falls into the ocean, will all the marine organisms die out of electrocution?

Tags: electricity

Saline water is said to be a good conductor of electricity. So if a live ac wire of 220 V, 50 Hz falls into the ocean, will all the marine organisms die out of electrocution? Has this never happened(live wire falling into the ocean)?

Comment: I think it is disappointing that people down-vote without telling the reason. This is not a frivolous question as the answer by @akhmeteli shows.

Comment: -1 for the post (v1) to apparently lack any sense of proportions.

Comment: @Qmechanic I don't think he means literally *all* the creatures in the entire ocean. It's a good question because it's a common TV trope that a wire falls into a swimming pool or pond and electrocutes whatever it is that the plot requires to be killed.

Comment: Then the post should be edited accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The effects of the live wire will only be strong near the live wire. If the current flowing through the wire after it fell into water is $I$, this current will propagate into a hemisphere of water, and the current density $j$ (and, consequently, the electric field $E=\sigma j$, where $\sigma$ is the conductivity of water) will decrease with distance.

Comment: And I guess it decreases $\propto r^{-2}$ (assuming a homogeneous isotropic system), correct?

Comment: @user1583209 : I guess so (approximately, at long distances), although the system is not quite homogeneous isotropic (it's a hemisphere, not a sphere)

Comment: Also, the current will take the path of least resistance. So an organism that has a higher electrical resistance than the water it is displacing will not have much current pass through it.

Comment: Also salinity (and conductivity which is related) are somewhat depending on depth, but I guess at those distances there is not much of a current left....